# Python script to pull data from RESTAPI fails with error

Tags: python

When I run my Python script to get data from RESTAPI of an application, I get the following error. I installed PIP and I installed requests package for the python. Here is my below query:

./simpleRunQuery.py `<args> <args>`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simpleRunQuery.py", line 25, in <module>
    res = requests.post(url, auth=(args.username, args.password), data=jsonRequest, headers=headers)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I can attach the script, but my script doens't have the lines 112 or 58 or any of these, it's a simple RESTAPI Script that queries and posts results here. Any pointers?

Comment: There are many possible causes for a connection abortion. The server can be misconfigured, firewall may block certain packets, ... You'll need to provide more information.

Comment: I can get to the same IP and port via browser, but the script is having issues.

Comment: It can also be a timeout from the server, as by default a POST request without explicit timeout set, will listen 'forever'. Do you have access to the server logs (around the same timestamp)?